# Compare complex subquery between two values

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I have repository with students and I want to get some students who have grades count in between 0 and 2.

This is my code:

```
_unitOfWork.Repository<Student>().Get(o => o.OrganizationId == organizationId
                && o.Grades.Where( o1 => o1.LastVersion
                        && o1.Type == 5
                        && o1.Value == 1).Count() > 0 
                && o.Grades.Where( o1 => o1.LastVersion
                        && o1.Type == 5
                        && o1.Value == 1).Count() <= 2 );
```

This code is working, but my question is how to change this query with less code.

Is there any way to replace Count with some variable and not use it two times in query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
 var values = Enumerable.Range(1, 2);

 _unitOfWork.Repository<Student>().Get(o => o.OrganizationId == organizationId
            && values.Contains(
                o.Grades.Where( o1 => o1.LastVersion
                    && o1.Type == 5
                    && o1.Value == 1).Count()
               ));
```

Comment: I can't use this query. It returns some error: "The type '<>f__AnonymousType0<orgId,cnt>' exists in both 'EDiary.Service.dll' and 'System.Web.dll'"
But what will this query return? Student object or new selected type {orgnanization, count}?

Comment: I've edited your answer by little, this is working for me! Thanks for your time and quick answer. Cheers :)